# Why does safari open the link from a script in index.html for a .net maui app

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0, maui-blazor, .net-8.0

I am working on an app using .NET MAUI and its been great. I have a feature where the user can load their wallet using a service called paystack. For this, I have added the script to the html and added the needed functions.
`<script src="https://js.paystack.co/v2/inline.js">`

... thereafter I can call the functions as I have setup. This runs well in android and I get a popup for the payment. The issue is with ios, on loading the app, safari instantly takes over, shortly after the splash, picks up the checkout url (from somewhere inside the script referenced in index.html) slides away the app and starts loading. Of course it never loads the payment modal. I know this may be hard to replicate but Im hopeful someone who knows about routing (I suspect its something in maui) could tell me if there's a way to prevent safari from detecting and firing up the script

I've tried using collocation, using JSRuntime and removing the script references. Removing the references prevents safari from taking over the app on loading, but I do not get the popup to work even on android.